# Having dificulties on assembling DE55 for Mastercard. Already have card tags and ARQC generated. Trying to test a cloud based authorizer

Tags: emv

Undestand that DE55 is build with CDOL1 tags plus card generated ARQC. Apparently does not  work.

Tried approach as described. Expect some directions .

Comment: DE55 is not built from CDOL data. The list of tags to be present in authorization message in DE55 is defined in CIS manual. CDOL data used in GAC command

Comment: CIS manual, details please?

Comment: IF CDOL11 tags are use to generate ARQC by chip, for the Authorizer to compute ARQC and compare, it must use the same data on CDOL1, isn´t it ?

Comment: Mastercard CIS (Customer Interface Specification) manual describes format of authorization message and content of DE55, including information about mandatory/optional set of tags

Answer (score 0):

I believe this clearly is not a legitimate request as you would have access to specification saying what you need to send.

Different systems require different data and acquirers may require more than they forward in the authorization request sent to issuer through network (CIS and other authorization protocols just define what is minimal that is a combination of what different card applications require).

You are also wrong on what data are used for cryptogram calculation as data elements found in CDOL are not enough to validate cryptogram.

Summarizing, you need to provide broader context, show what you have done and start with asking your acquirer what data is required to be sent - no other way to do it.